# Is the sound coming from the iphone or the watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, watchkit

I have two simulated apple devices. One is an iphone the other is  simulated watch connected to the same phone.

Is there anyway to indicate or determine if a played sound is coming from the simulated iphone or the watch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No. It is not possible to play sounds with WatchKit on the Apple Watch.

This is in Apple's Watchkit FAQ in their Developer Forums.

You could trigger a sound to play on the iPhone from a button press on the Watch but you can't play a sound directly from the Watch.

Comment: Is it still possible to play on the iPhone in WatchOS 2 or 3? I can't get sound to play on the iPhone but I could on WatchOS 1.

Answer (score 2):

cant you just log an output when the sound is played to see which one its played from ?

Comment: All code is run from the phone, so any log would be coming from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an audio hijack application to capture the audio of a particular app. "Audio Hijack" is one, there are many.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer true.  You can use WKInterfaceInlineMovie to play sound on the watch using a button tap on the watch, for example.
For a fuller explanation, see my response to this question:

[Is there REALLY no way to play short sounds on Apple watch without a UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463170/is-there-really-no-way-to-play-short-sounds-on-apple-watch-without-a-ui/48362039#48362039])