# Is there REALLY no way to play short sounds on Apple watch without a UI?

Tags: audio, watchkit, watchos-2

As a learning exercise I decided to write a Simon game for Apple Watch (iOS 9.3, WatchKit 2.0).

I created 4 short piano note sounds in GarageBand. I converted them to MP3 files in Audacity, only to find that Apple Watch doesn't support MP3. Ok, great. I need to convert them to WAV or CAF files. Sigh...

Anyway, looking into it, it looks like the only way to play any sounds at all is to display a media controller on the watch. (Using either  `presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion:` or `WKInterfaceMovie`.

I just want to play different 1/4 second piano sounds as the user presses buttons.

Is there any other way with the current WatchKit, that doesn't require displaying a media controller?

Comment: This answer says you can do it if you have a bluetooth headset synced... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31759799/1671729  Apart from that, I agree wholeheartedly with Apple's practice not matching real world...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I saw that thread, and have confirmed that that code only works if you have a Bluetooth device paired. If not you get a message requesting you to connect one. Very odd.

Comment: Have you submitted [a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/)? While it won't help solve the "current WatchKit" dilemma, Apple does pay attention to the number of requests for a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

Using watchOS4 I got it to work using WKInterfaceMovie. It's not that onerous, and much better than `presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL`.   Using IB, you need to drag a WKInterfaceInlineMovie object onto the watch face (resize it very small - you won't see it)  Connect the object to your WKInterfaceController:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myMovie: WKInterfaceInlineMovie!
```

I dragged a couple of buttons onto the interface controller, and call the following with an identifier for the correct sound file, from the IBAction associated with the button:

```
   func playSound(numberOfNote: Int) {
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "note\(numberOfNote)", withExtension: "wav")!
        myMovie.setMovieURL(soundURL)
        myMovie.playFromBeginning()
    }
```

I click on a button and the sound plays out loud (without earphones) immediately (unlike the other method which has a lengthy pause plus the presented controller needs to be dismissed). This should be perfect for your stated needs.